# Is there a way to create a static website using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on displaying information on a website where it forces all the web pages to be static. For certain reasons, I would like to use cshtml since I need to bring in a lot of data and represent it on a page and I have been told that this would be the ideal way to do it. I am very new to ASP.NET MVC but I have some HTML and CSS experience and have worked with JavaFX in the past. Any ideas/tips on how I would accomplish this would be helpful.

I have created the default ASP.NET MVC solution in Visual Studio 2015 Professional and have removed a majority of the template that is not necessary. I have been told by my mentors that I need to find a way to make the webpage static. I have an idea about creating a single web page where the user scrolls down to see information with buttons on the top to take them to certain locations on the page but I am unsure if I can create this in MVC and still be static.

Comment: Unsure how the word _static_ is being defined (combined with _"cshtml to bring in a lot of data..."_). If you don't want the "weight" of MVC and use cshtml, you can do [Asp.Net Web Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/)  (aka "Razor web site") - link will also show you same in `Core`.

Comment: There is a tool that harvests an asp.net site into a set of static files: [ssg](https://www.camiloterevinto.com/post/generating-static-sites-from-asp-net-core-mvc-apps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.cshtml pages are runtime compiled and then returned by being written to the response stream by the routing mechanism of asp.net mvc. It is not possible to both use .cshtml and simultaneously return a .html page.

That said, it is easy to create the feel of a static page, although it will require you using the routing in asp.net mvc.

You would just return a view and then use layout = null.

StaticController.cs

```
public StaticController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Example() { return View(); }
}
```

/Views/Static/Example.cshtml

```
@{ Layout = null; }
<html>
<body>
    <div>Static Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```